# having trouble with java.lang.NullPointerException error, please help me

Tags: oop, nullpointerexception

`enter code here`I have a private boolean `exist=false;`, this is a local variable of my `payrool class`

I also have a method `searchRecord(int payrollPeriod, int empNo)`

```
public void searchRecord(int payrollPeriod, int empNo)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<100;x++)
        {
            if(trans[x].getPayrollPeriod() == payrollPeriod && trans[x].getEmpNo() == empNo)
            {
                payrollCounter=x;
                exist=true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

My array `trans[]` is a `Transaction` type (I used composition) consist of record which has `payrollPeriod` and `empNo`.

My program runs fine whenever files exist, but when the search is resulted to false `java.lang.NullPointerException` happens...

please help me, what should I do

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at payroll.Payroll.searchRecord(Payroll.java:350)
at payroll.Payroll.actionPerformed(Payroll.java:184)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

TRANSACTION CLASS:

```
package payroll;

public class Transaction extends Employee
{
//local variable
private int payrollPeriod;
private double hoursWorked;

//constructor
public Transaction(int payrollPeriod, int empNo, String name, String department, double payRate, double hoursWorked)
{
    super(empNo, name, department, payRate);
    this.payrollPeriod=payrollPeriod;
    this.hoursWorked=hoursWorked;
}

//methods
public int getPayrollPeriod()
{
    return payrollPeriod;
}
public double getHoursWorked()
{
    return hoursWorked;
}
}
```

Comment: post the code of getPayrollPeriod() and getEmpNo()

Comment: Maybe nulls in that array? And why the hard-coded 100? `trans.length` seems more maintainable.

Comment: Show us the actual exception. Is `trans[x]` null or is it something inside the methods?

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: In your array trans[] how many Transaction objects are there

Comment: Please add the stacktrace.

http://www.allegro.com/papers/how_to_ask_for_help.html

Comment: i just have less than 10 elements in my trans[]

Comment: I already added the stack trace and Transaction class

Answer (score 1):

The array `trans[x]` contains `null` values.

You should either:

1. Not allow `null` values in the array when building it.
2. Check for `null` values in the loop and skip/handle them.

   ```
   public void searchRecord(int payrollPeriod, int empNo) {
       for(int x = 0; x < trans.length; x++) {
           if (trans[x] == null) {
               System.out.println("Skipped null value in trans[x]");
               continue;
           }

           if (trans[x].getPayrollPeriod() == payrollPeriod && trans[x].getEmpNo() == empNo) {
               payrollCounter = x;
               exist = true;
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```